# growth of infinitely generated groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there any length function on additive group of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that  $\mathbb{Q}$ is of polynomial growth WRT this length function? What about the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Q}$ instead?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Q} =\mathcal{Q}$ the rationals?

Comment: Take the length function defined by the generating set which is the entire group.

Comment: sorry my mistake I meant $\mathbb{Q}$.

If I take the length function defined by a generating set its growth would be infinite. I need somehow manipulate the length function coming from a generating set to get a polynomial growth. And if it is impossible I need to prove it.

Comment: I see, I was thinking that after one gigantic, all encompassing ball of radius 1, there would be no more growth at all, but that's not what you mean....... 

Comment: @Vahid: What is your definition of a length function? The standard notion of word length is used only for finitely-generated groups. I guess, you want to define $|x|$ axiomatically so that $|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$, $\{x: |x|\le n\}$ is finite for all $n\in {\mathbb N}$, etc. Until you clearly state what axioms you want, your question makes no sense. 

Comment: By a length function on a group $G$ I mean a function $l:G\rightarrow [0,\infty[$ such that $l(1)=0$, $l(gh)\leq l(g) +l(h)$ and $l(g)=l(g^{-1})$. 

I need to see if there is a length function $l$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ and a polynomial $P$ such that, for all $r\geq 0$, the cardinality of the set $\{g\in \mathbb{Q} ; l(g)\leq r\}$ is less than $P(r)$.  

As you might guessed, the positive answer to the above question proves that $\mathbb{Q}$ has property (RD) (Rapid decay) and a negative answer shows that $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have property (RD) (because $\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian and so is amenable).

Comment: @Misha: Vahid's definition of length is standard. You maybe had in mind "word length".

Comment: @Vahid: I am aware of Jolissaint's paper "Rapidly decreasing functions in reduced C^*-algebras of groups" which proves that an amenable group has the rapid decay property if and only if it has polynomial growth. However, in the in the "if" direction he assumes finitely generated. Is there a reference for that without an assumption of finite generation?

Comment: @Misha: with the word length function, of course the growth is not even finite. so one needs to manipulate the word length function to obtain a polynomial growth(of course if it is possible).

Comment: @Lee: If we look at the proof of the same theorem in the following paper, we see that the amenability is enough to prove (RD) implies the polynomial growth. Of course, one has to show that the growth is finite, which is not a big deal. 

The paper is: Some geometric groups with rapid decay. GAFA, vol 15, 2005 311--339, By I. Chatterji and K. Ruane

Comment: @Yves: There are several things in the literature called "length functions", for instance, there is one due to Lyndon, which is different from Vahid's. The difficulty, as I see it, is that growth rate will depend on the choice of a length function (even for infinite cyclic groups one can get a super-exponential rate of growth). 

Comment: @Misha. You're right; actually for a f.g. group, the word length achieves the minimal growth rate among all lengths. The interest is to  make things meaningful with infinitely generated groups. In this case there is no "largest" length and, in general, no length with "smallest " growth. Lengths are also useful when you want to consider countable groups as metric spaces up to coarse equivalence (extending viewing f.g. groups as metric spaces up to QI). [I refer to Lyndon's lengths as "Lyndon lengths" because it's a much more specific context in my opinion.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes for $\mathbf{Q}$, no for $\mathbf{Q}^*$.

For $\mathbf{Q}$, write it as the union of an increasing sequence $L_n$ with $L_1=\mathbf{Z}$ and $L_n$ of finite index over $L_1$. Pick a function $F$ with fast growth and define $l'(r)=|r|+F(\sup\{n:r\notin L_n\})$.

For $\mathbf{Q}^*$, it contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}^d$ for every $d$, so for every length the growth is at least polynomial of degree $d$. So it can't be polynomial.

Added-1: for $\mathbf{Q}$ we can arrange so that $[L_n:L_1]\le n$ for all $n$. Then we can pick $F$ to be the identity and then the growth is at most quadratic.

Added-2: the argument extends, showing that an abelian group admits a length with polynomial growth iff it's countable and has finite $\mathbf{Q}$-rank.

Comment: $F$ does not have to be tremendously fast-growing. $F=[L_n:L_0]$ will make it a group of quadratic growth.

Comment: @Will I was unable to check your claim (which looks correct) but I edited taking it into account. @Lee: I maintain $\sup$ and $\notin$ (but fixed a confusing typo since I forgot the word "union").

Comment: @Yves Thank you very much for your answers. 
@Will Thank you for your comment.
Please see my other question titled "property (RD)" for $\mathbb{Q}$ where I am going to answer it  using Yves' help (in the next 30 minuets). 